# Windows 7 setup could not see HDD

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, boot, windows-installation

I'm trying to install Windows 7 on a Lenovo Desktop Core i5 PC, which originally came with Windows 7 installed, I bought it used and hard disk was cleaned.

When I run the Windows 7 setup it could not see HDD (C:) but if I switch Windows 7 setup to advance mode and select command prompt I can see C: drive, I can even copy files from D: (DVD Rom) to C: drive.  I took out HDD and attached to some other PC and format it then try to run the setup again but no luck.

Its a 300Gb SATA drive, I can see it in BIOS and as I mentioned while using command prompt I can even copy files to it.  Not sure do I need some boot loader for Hard drives?

General google bring me some solutions related to BIOS settings I tried all of them but no luck.

Comment: Is UEFI or Legacy Mode enabled

Comment: I tried both one by one, even I had option to set to auto, so I tried that as well.

Comment: How it boots is how it install (rule). Windows strictly requires MBR ("msdos") partitioning BIOS/Legacy mode and GPT for UEFI mode (another rule, Windows only). If the drive shows up but doesn't allow installing on it then you have a mismatch. If it doesn't show at all then probably the drive mode is set to something not supported by the version you're using. The OEM installation may have had additional drivers slipstreamed to support it, or be a later edition (service pack), etc. Too many variables here and for what? Win7 is out of support for a long time. Using it online IS dangerous.

Comment: Specific model of Lenovo?

Comment: Its M Series ThinkCentre